# Custom events not logged in the AppInsights when called the TP rom ValidationTechnicalProfile

Tags: logging, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, appinsights

I have added the technical profile to log the custom events in the AppInsights and called the technical profile from the sign-in TP's ValidationTechnicalProfile section, but the logs are not recorded in the AppInsights. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Technical Profile to Log in App Insights

```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="AppInsights-CustomSigninActiveCheck">
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="EventType" PartnerClaimType="eventName" DefaultValue="IsActiveStatusCheck" />           
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="{property:objectId}" DefaultValue="Not Applicable" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="{property:signInName}" DefaultValue="Not Applicable" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isUserActive" />
      </InputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AppInsights-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Called the TP from the Sign-in TP

```
</OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>      
              <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-CheckActiveStatus" />             
                <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AppInsights-CustomSigninActiveCheck">                
              </ValidationTechnicalProfile> 
              <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive">              
              </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
      </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Does it work if you call it from an orchestration step directly? Because this should be working, so I suspect it’s not to do with where you call it from, but rather your config.

Comment: It is working when i call from orchestration step, but not working when it is called from validation technical profile

Comment: Is REST-CheckActiveStatus returning a success response? If it's returning a 4xx response then your validation will stop at that step and logging won't run.

Comment: REST-CheckActiveStatus is giving 200

Comment: Is `login-NonInteractive` running? The snippet looks like it should work fine to me, the only thing I can see is that your latter two `ValidationTechnicalProfile` steps don't use self-closing tags, though I wouldn't have expected that to be a problem tbh.